# Does math.fmod have a higher precision than %?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I get the following:

```
>>> x=1234567890123456789012345678
>>> odd = x + 1
>>> odd
1234567890123456789012345679
>>> math.fmod(x, 2)
0.0
>>> math.fmod(odd, 2)
0.0
>>> odd % 2
1
```

Is there something wrong with `math.fmod(odd, 2)`?

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html#number-theoretic-and-representation-functions), math.fmod(x,y) is:

> Return `fmod(x, y)`, as defined by the platform C library. Note that the Python expression `x % y` may not return the same result. The intent of the C standard is that fmod(x, y) be exactly (mathematically; to infinite precision) equal to `x - n*y` for some integer n such that the result has the same sign as x and magnitude less than `abs(y)`.

The above sounds like math.fmod(x,y) should return x modulo y.

Comment: I added the Python language tag since you seem to be discussing Python and it's a language and library specific question.

Comment: `import sys;print sys.float_info`

Comment: @thebjorn Are you saying I have exceeded the limits? Odd there were no overflow exceptions.

Comment: It doesn't overflow, it just loses precision.

Answer (score 7):

The C function `fmod` works on double precision (i.e. 64 bit) floating point values.  Python has to convert the arguments to double precision floating point before calling `fmod`.  Your `x` cannot be represented exactly as such a floating point value.  For a number that large, the "unit of least precision" ([ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) is greater than one.  A quick check of this:

```
In [3]: x = 1234567890123456789012345678

In [4]: fx = 1.0*x

In [5]: fx
Out[5]: 1.2345678901234569e+27

In [6]: fx + 1
Out[6]: 1.2345678901234569e+27

In [7]: fx + 1 == fx
Out[7]: True
```

Perhaps a more direct demonstration is to note that `x` and `x + 1` result in the same value when converted to floating point:

```
In [11]: float(x) == float(x + 1)
Out[11]: True
```

`float(x + 1)` is the same as `float(x)`, so it is not surprising that `fmod` doesn't return the value that you expected.

Comment: What modules are available to operate on very large integers?

Comment: Python handles very large integers!  Just don't pass them to `fmod`.